# How to list all documents in a mongodb collection in ascending order mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

I am trying to list the documents in my level collection by the lowest level to the highest, but that is not working. My code is

```
const lvl = await Level.find({}).sort({level: 1});
```

for the filter, and I list it over here:

```
    lvl.forEach(entry => {
        embed.addFields({ name: `Level ${entry.level}`, value: `Xp Required: ${entry.xp}`});
    })
```

The code for the level schema is:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const LevelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    level: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
    xp: mongoose.Schema.Types.String,
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("levels", LevelSchema);
```

This code is working completely fine, the only issue is that it comes in the order that the documents are in the collection, and not by the lowest level to the highest like I want it to. I did what the documentation told me to do in the `.sort({level: 1})` part, but that didn't change anything either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use mapping your array, lets re-construct your code for a bit:

this part of your code is okay:

```js
await Level.find({}).sort({level: 1});
```

But you might need to do it as `Array Object`. So to work this out. Change the code line to

```js
Level.find({}).sort([['level', 'ascending']]); //remove the await
//ascending = 1, descending = -1
```

Adding the `.exec()` will do the trick:

```js
Level.find({})
.sort([['level', 'ascending']])
.exec((err, res) => {
   if(res) {
     //There's an existing data
     //Let's use your method on embed.
     let embed = new MessageEmbed()
     .setDescription("OPTIONAL")
     .setColor("YOUR_COLOR")
     .setTitle("OPTIONAL")
     .setTimestamp() //OPTIONAL
     const result = res.map((value, index) => {
        return(embed.addFields({name: `Level: ${res[index].level}`, value: `Xp Required: ${res[index].exp}`}))
     }).join("\n");
     result

     message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]})
   } else {
     //No data message
   }
})
```

Since the sorting detects only the first number, you need to add `.collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})`.

from this:

```js
Level.find({}).sort([['level', 'ascending']])
```

Turn it to this:

```js
Level.find({}).sort([['level', 'ascending']]).collation({locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true})
```

Comment: This does help, but sometimes there are issues with it not working like for example it listed level 1 and skipped to 10 then listed to 16 and then went back for the other numbers. They were in order most of the time but some were not. I dont understand why this is happening but I think there is something wrong with the res.map

Comment: No, there's no problem about mapping. The only problem is that the mongoose only looking for the first number, to solve this kind of matthers, you need to add the `collation()`, see my edited post